# Slow motion video like TWIXTOR for vse

Tags: edit-mode, video-sequence-editor, video

How could I achieve the Twixtor effect with the VSE ([Twixtor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-aEsRdT5xI) in After Effects).

Comment: Hi, could you please describe what "effect" you actually want? Questions should be complete in themselves without needing to watch external videos.

Comment: I can't explain it in too much detail, it's basically a transition effect that kinda looks like slow motion but really smooth and a bit more warped, I tried my best but it's easier to see the video and without it the question is really difficult to answer

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Twixtor, and other apps that do slow motion, use a technology called Optical Flow that estimates motion vectors to create interpolation.
There is no way, that I'm aware of, to do optical flow in blender.

Blender has no temporal interpolation for video other than repeat or drop frames, or cross-fade (frame-blend) between two frames.

None of those will give you the smoothness of extreme slow motion.

For an open source alternative to do optical flow re-timing try

http://slowmovideo.granjow.net/

or

https://linuxhint.com/slowmovideo-slow-motion-video-marker/

Comment: another free alternative is Davinci Resolve free.

Comment: @brockmann you are right. Optical flow and Speed warp are for paying customers only...  still a bit cheaper than twixtor, and a much better editor than the VSE.

Comment: That's for sure @susu

Answer (score -2):

Blender 2.90 has an option to use frame-blend interpolation. You'll find it in the speed strip settings:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, but the question is about [optical flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_flow) right?